# Building static OpenCV with ffmpeg is still looking for shared libavcodec

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, static-linking, libavcodec

I'm trying to build a static OpenCV Python with ffmpeg enabled to run on AWS Lambda. I Need to upload OpenCV my cv2.so in a zip file.

To do so I set the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` and `WITH_FFPMEG=YES`. But when doing import cv2 in the Python shell, I get the error:

```
ImportError: libavcodec.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I set `WITH_FFPMEG=NO` I don't get this error anymore but I need ffmpeg to read a video.

What I would like to do is OpenCV to use the static libavcodec library not the shared one. I thought setting up BUILD_SHARE_LIBS to off would be enough but it's not. T

here are no flags in the cmake file which let you specified the path to libavcodec. I've been looking for sometimes but I can't find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible as ffmpeg is using LGPL license https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5920. I haven't find another solution yet to run on lambda.

Comment: I am also implementing this feature and facing the same issue. Are you able to solve this issue? If yes, please specify the method.